# XML attribute to Webpage Request

Tags: xml, json, xmlhttprequest

How can i send request to the URL:8080 port and get the Text output and Authenticate too ?

```
<field label_name="Get Results" type="button" link="http://URL:8080/" authenti_username="***" authenti_password="***" service_method="POST" server_athenti_method="Basic" ssl_certificate="None" ssl_key="None" response_contains="text" output="text"/>
```

Comment: You want to send a request to the URL which requires some authentication. you want to do it from `javascript`. Is it what you are asking?

Comment: @Joshi yah...crt...from js or php ..any kind..

Answer (score 1):

```
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.open('GET', 'some url', true);
xml.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth); // <<<<----- USED HERE
xml.send();
```

You can do this way or your can also use `jQuery ajax call`

**Update upon REQUEST:**

```
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.open('GET', 'http://URL:8080', true);
xml.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "BASIC eHh4Onl5eQ=="); // <<<<----- USED HERE
xml.send();
```

`eHh4Onl5eQ==` is base64 encode form of username:password i.e xxx:yyy. You can do the conversion online [here](http://www.base64encode.org/).

Try it out, it's a pseudo code.

Comment: can you be more specific.. first i got url lyk 8080 port.. [http://URL:8080/dir] which has Authentication like username:xxx password:yyy , and i have to POST two values over the url and get the text output..can you mention the coding part ?

Comment: Now how can i POST some 2 parameters over the authenticated URL.. ? lyk data1 & data2 and get text output ?

Comment: in that `xml.send()` you can pass an `FormData` object. try it out by yourself.